# populating listview with parse in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm developing an Android App with a Listview populated with a database in Parse.

I can connect my list view with parse and by this side everything is working. The problem is that I want to show one image and three text in the row of the Listview but the app only shows the image and one text. I can't show the image 150x100dp only a small image is showed.

I don't know how to show all data in the row.

This is my code.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
private CustomAdapter urgentTodosAdapter;
private ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado_musica;


    // Initialize main ParseQueryAdapter
    mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "Musica");
    mainAdapter.setTextKey("titulo");
    mainAdapter.setTextKey("artista");
    mainAdapter.setTextKey("album");
    mainAdapter.setImageKey("imagen");

    // Initialize the subclass of ParseQueryAdapter
    urgentTodosAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);

    // Initialize ListView and set initial view to mainAdapter
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
    mainAdapter.loadObjects();


}
}
```

custom_list.xml

```
<com.parse.ParseImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagen"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/no_picture"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titulo"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:text="titulo"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imagen"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/artista"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:text="artista"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagen"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titulo"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/titulo" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:text="album"
    android:id="@+id/album"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagen"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/artista"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/artista"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp" />
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter {

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    // Use the QueryFactory to construct a PQA that will only show
    // Todos marked as high-pri
    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Musica");
            //query.whereEqualTo("high pry", "true");
            return query;
        }
    });
}

// Customize the layout by overriding getItemView
@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_list, null);
    }

    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

    // Add and download the image
    ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("imagen");
    if (imageFile != null) {
        todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
        todoImage.loadInBackground();
    }

    // Add the title view
    TextView titleTextView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
    titleTextView1.setText(object.getString("titulo"));

    // Add a reminder of how long this item has been outstanding
    TextView titleTextView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.localidad);
    titleTextView2.setText(object.getString("artista"));

    TextView titleTextView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.consola);
    titleTextView3.setText(object.getString("album"));


    return v;
}
}
```

activity_listado_musica.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Someone can help me? I think I'm doing something wrong in the adapter but I don't know what.

I have followed and read the Android Parse Guide and mealspott tutorial and I can'f find what is wrong in my code.

thanks in advance regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/) link. it worked very good for me.

Another solution is to change on CustomAdapter.java this line:

```
textView.setText(object.getString("String");
```

To

```
textView.setText((String) object.get("String");
```

Comment: I'm trying. I knew this tutorial but my code is working only that it doesn't show what I want. Following this tutorial I have to re-write all the code and I think, the problem is something easy to solve, perhaps in the CustomAdapter. But I'm trying with this tutorial.

Comment: @Rec I've added anther solution that might help you

Comment: Hi Ido, thanks again, sorry I didn't see your answer two days ago. I tried today and it doesn't work. I will continuo with the androidbeginin tutorial.

Comment: Hi Ido, I have implemented my code with Androidbeggining tutorial and I have a mistake in my code, I don't know why 'ImageLoader' give me an error 'Cannot resolve symbol ImageLoader', do you know what I have to check? Thanks